# iOS parsing a jsonDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am from php domain, and now learning ios coding. I want to make a view with one part showing user info, and a table showing friends details.

I can get the json Logged correctly.

My json looks like this:

```
{"Me":
      {"username":"aVC",
       "userID":1
      },
 "Friends":
      [{"username":"Amm",
       "userID":2
       },...

       ]
}
```

Here is what I use.

```
 NSError *error;
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"jS: %@", json);
```

this works fine. I want to seperate the two sections (Me, and friends), and then use it to fill tables. Can someone throw some ideas?

NOTE: I am not using any frameworks. Just NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Use NSLog to examine the dictionary (which will look a lot like the original JSON). Extract the individual dictionary elements as needed, and further process them.  It's really quite simple if you just take it one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code after obtaining the `json` dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *me = [json objectForKey:@"Me"];
NSArray *friends = [json objectForKey:@"Friends"];
```

This should let you pull the information from the `@"Me"` and `@"Friends"` into separate variables.

Comment: `friends` isn't a dictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks You're right, I missed these square brackets, it looks like an array of dictionaries.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks. The "Friends" part can be one or more, so the square bracket may not be there all the time. Does that matter? Also, how would I access the individual elements? say first friend, id, etc?

Comment: @aVC I would assume that square brackets would always be there, even when the number of friends is one or zero: it makes sense to pass it as an array. Once you have an array of friends, you can use all methods of `NSArray` to access its individual elements: `NSDictionary *firstFriend = [friends objectAtIndex:0]`, `NSNumber *myId = [me objectForKey:@"userID"]`, and so on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks very much. I think I got the idea now. :)